# Getting "too many rows" error inside a "for" cursor loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle9i

I have a trigger that contains two cursors loops, one nested inside the other like this:

```
FOR outer_rec IN outer_cursor
LOOP
  FOR inner_rec IN inner_cursor
  LOOP
     -- Do some calculations
  END LOOP;

END LOOP;
```

Somewhere in this it is throwing the following error:

ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

I've been trying to determine where it's coming from for an hour or so.. but should this error never happen?

Also.. I am assuming the inner loop automatically closes and opens itself again every time the outer loop goes the next record, i hope this is correct.

Comment: Do you have a `SELECT` ..`INTO` in the inner loop?

Comment: i double checked and i don't have any SELECT INTO, or FETCH statements inside either loop.its mostly a series of IF statements like:
IF inner_rec.x IS NULL THEN.. etc

Comment: @Will No dynamic SQL ? (eg: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` )

Comment: @Will: We aren't psychic.  If you want help, abstract what you can but post some detail.

Comment: Any procedures or functions being called that execute their own SQL?

Comment: Any Update statements inside either loop?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, `ORA-01422` gets triggered only if you have a `SELECT...INTO` statement in the PL/SQL block, where the select statement fetches more than 1 row. Remember that a `SELECT..INTO` can fetch only a single row, if more than one row gets fetched, the above exception gets raised.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the 1422 on an UPDATE statement that does a SELECT for its values.

Are you not getting a stack trace with a line number?

Answer (score 0):

I was calling a stored procedure that had an OUT variable, and somehow when it tried to use the out variable, this error occured.